# compare correlation between two matrices

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, descriptive-statistics, model-comparison, agreement-statistics

We have two algorithms that assign a score to the foreground of how well it fits the background. And we want to know which algorithm is closer to human perception. Then we collect an evaluation set that for each background, people will assign a score to each foreground.

Then for each of algorithm A, algorithm B, and human judgment, we have a matrix (x-axis background, y-axis foreground, value score). We want to know which algorithm is closer to human perception.

What statistic method we should use? Notice score of algorithms A, B and human can not be compared directly (not the same scale).

Comment: Do the entries of one matrix correspond to the entries of the other up to the distinction of whether the entry was human-generated vs computer generated? If yes, you can unpack the matrix and compute familiar correlation coefficients on them. If the rows correspond, but the columns may or may not correspond, then consider seeing if [CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) is suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Pearson Correlation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) and [*Spearman Rank Correlation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) coefficients could be used to measure correlation with human judgements for different algorithms.

Comment: The problem is that both Pearson and  Spearman work on vector, my data is a matrix. And the matrix contains structure information, i can not reshape it to a vector. Is there other correlation I can use?

Comment: @ZongzeWu What is "structure information" here? It isn't clear what is precluding the reshaping of the matrix here.

Comment: Matrices *are* vectors.  (They have additional structure, but that doesn't override their vector nature!)